# searching key value of dictionary of list in another list of dictionary in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, nested-loops

I have 1 query regarding dictionary operation in python.

I am trying to write a python code and my scenario is as below:

```
dict1 = {'a1':[1,2,3,4], 'b1':["Hi", "How are you", "I am good", "where are you"]}

List1 = [{'a1': 3, 'c1': "This is python", 'b1': "Where are you", 'd1': 56},
         {'a1': 6, 'c1': "This is python", 'b1': "This is dummy code", 'd1': 56},
         {'a1': 9, 'c1': "This is python", 'b1': "How are you", 'd1': 56},
         {'a1': 2, 'c1': "This is python", 'b1': "Hi", 'd1': 56}   ]
```

As seen above, i have 1 dictionary of list and 1 list of dictionary.

Now i have to write the code in such a way that i get a list of dictionary from "List1" such that it contains only those entries that matches dict1.
So from above example, the expected out is as below:

expected output:

```
res = [{'a1': 3, 'c1': "This is python", 'b1': "Where are you", 'd1': 56},
       {'a1': 2, 'c1': "This is python", 'b1': "Hi", 'd1': 56}   ]
```

Above result because a1 and b1 are matching

Below is the code that i tried so far

```
res = []
filterargs = dict1.items()  
for keydata, valuedata in filterargs:
    for filtervalue in valuedata:
        for data in List1:
            if (data['a1'] == filtervalue):
                res.append(data)
```

Now the prob is, i am able to do comparison of single key/value in above for loop and for doing second level of comparison, i will again have to run the for loop code on "res" list, which will be too much overhead.

Moreover currently i have show dict1 has only 2 keys, but its configurable and it can even have c1 and d1 if user configures it (I am using the above code in 1 function and using **Kwargs for dynamic size dict handelling).

Can someone suggest a cleaner and simple way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Use `all()` to test each of the keys and filter lists and return `True` only if all of them match.

```
filterargs = list(dict1.items())
for data in List1:
    if all(data.get(key) in values for key, values in filterargs):
        res.append(data)
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar for the reply. With above code snippet, i am seeing complete "List1" is going inside "res". Though i will try to use "any keyword" and see if i can get something from this

Comment: I just tried it. My result didn't include `{'a1': 6, 'c1': "This is python", 'b1': "This is dummy code", 'd1': 56}`

Comment: Maybe you want `all()` instead of `any()`.

Comment: If I do that I just get `[{'a1': 2, 'c1': 'This is python', 'b1': 'Hi', 'd1': 56}]`. `Where are you` doesn't match because it has an uppercase `W` but the filter is lowercase.

Comment: Hey Barmar, thanks for the comment. yes with "ALL" i am getting the expected output.